# DX9 GetMessage FPS Drop

Tags: directx, directx-9

my program is a transparent overlay over a game
code that sets it to the game window
setwindowtotarget is called in a seperate thread
i am very frusturated
also, the game feels laggy when my fps counter says i'm getting over 200 as well

```
void SetWindowToTarget(){
while(true){
    tWnd = FindWindow(0, tWindowName);
    if (tWnd)
    {
        GetWindowRect(tWnd, &tSize);
        Width = tSize.right - tSize.left;
        Height = tSize.bottom - tSize.top;
        DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(tWnd, GWL_STYLE);
        if(dwStyle & WS_BORDER)
        {
            tSize.top += 23;
            Height -= 23;
        }
        MoveWindow(hWnd, tSize.left, tSize.top, Width, Height, true);
    }
    Sleep(5000);
}
```

}

this code makes my fps drop down and then back up every 10 seconds or so

```
while (GetMessage(&Message, NULL, 0, 0)){
    TranslateMessage(&Message);
    DispatchMessage(&Message);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
Sleep(17);
switch (Message)
{   
case WM_PAINT:
    Render();
    break;

case WM_CREATE:
    DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &Margin);
    break;

case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(1);
    return 0;

default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    break;
}
return 0;
```

}

render func:

```
int Render(){
p_Device->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, 0, 1.0f, 0);
p_Device->BeginScene();

if(tWnd == GetForegroundWindow()){
    g_vCenterScreen.x = Width / 2.f;
    g_vCenterScreen.y = Height / 2.f;
//draw stuff
    }
}

p_Device->EndScene();
p_Device->PresentEx(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: 1. You should use PeekMessage instead of GetMessage
2. I'm not sure it's a good idea to call MoveWindow in a loop in a separate thread. Maybe you can call it only once.

Comment: Why? I was told that GetMessage was better for performance.

Comment: The low FPS feel was even worse when I was using just peekmessage in a while loop. After changing it to GetMessage the fps got a bit better.. but it still isn't great

Comment: GetMessage is a blocking call, while PeekMessage is a non blocking

Comment: You can use PeekMessage in a loop with a Sleep(1) on each iteration.

Comment: I did that.. DWM uses less CPU but the game feels laggy even though the game fps counter is 200+

Comment: Then maybe your problem is related to constant MoveWindow calls